# Django to_python method of custom models.DateTimeField not receiving the correct value

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a ModelForm based on a model which includes a customized DateTimeField.  The only customization is to override the to_python method so I can convert the 'AM/PM' formatted string into a 24 hr time format that Django will validate.  I specified a DateTimeInput widget on the form so I could format into AM/PM notation (format=('%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M %p')), which I initialize to the current datetime.  The form displays correctly, eg '10/10/2021 04:33 PM' but when the to_python function of the custom field is called, the value passed to it does not include the time; only the date.  Also, I don't understand why the to_python method of that field is called (twice) when a listener on another field creates an AJAX call rather than when the Submit button is clicked.  I looked at the request data sent when the Submit is clicked, and it does have the full '10/10/2021 04:33 PM'.  (I realize the actual conversion in to_python to handle the AM/PM is not done at all; I haven't gotten that far yet).  I tried using several popular datetimepickers instead, but none of them solved this problem.

models.py:

```
class ampmDateTimeField (models.DateTimeField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        print ('initial_date_time = ',value)
        # Here is where the code will go to do the actual conversion
        # for now, just see what the super's conversion is doing
        converted_date_time = super().to_python(value)
        print ('converted_date_time = ',converted_date_time)
        return converted_date_time


class Encounter(SafeDeleteModel):
    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE
    encounter_date = ampmDateTimeField()
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    handling_time = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    crate_time = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    holding_time = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (self.user.username + '/' + self.animal.Name)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("encounter-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

forms.py:

```
class Open_Encounter_Form(ModelForm):
    numPerDayField = CharField(label='Today\'s uses')
    #aNumField = CharField(name='Today',max_length=4)

    class Meta:
        model = Encounter        
        fields = ['encounter_date','animal','numPerDayField','user','handling_time','crate_time','holding_time','comments']
        widgets = {
            'comments': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40}),
            'encounter_date': DateTimeInput(format=('%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M %p'), attrs={'size':'24'}),
        }
```

views.py:

```
def open_encounter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('request: ', request.POST)
        form = Open_Encounter_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #save the data
            aRecord=form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        
    else:
        current_user = request.user
        form=Open_Encounter_Form(initial={'encounter_date': datetime.datetime.today(),'user': current_user})
    return render(request, 'openencounter.html', {'form': form})
```

openencounter.html:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>New Encounter</h1>
<form action="/encounters/openencounter/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#id_animal").change(function () {
    var url = "{% url 'animal-data-API' %}"
    console.log('url:',url)
    var animalId = $("#id_animal").val();
    console.log('animalID: ', animalId);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            'animal': animalId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('returned data:',data);
            uses = data['uses'];
            theMax = data['theMax'];
            if (uses > theMax) {
                $("#id_numPerDayField").css("color", "red")
            } else if (uses == theMax) {
                $("#id_numPerDayField").css("color", "blue")
            } else {
                $("#id_numPerDayField").css("color", "black")
            }
            theStr = uses.toString() + ' (out of ' + theMax.toString() + ')'
            $("#id_numPerDayField").val(theStr)
        }
    });
})
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

terminal output:

1. when form is opened:

```
[10/Oct/2021 13:16:25] "GET /encounters/openencounter/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4508
[10/Oct/2021 13:16:25] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 77
```

2. when user makes a selection in a choice field dropdown causing AJAX call:

```
initial_date_time =  2021-10-10
converted_date_time =  2021-10-10 00:00:00
initial_date_time =  2021-10-10 00:00:00
converted_date_time =  2021-10-10 00:00:00
[10/Oct/2021 13:18:00] "GET /encounters/api/load_animal_uses/?animal=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 24
```

3. when user clicks Submit button:

```
request:  <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['LOH28mXa5QTdomcPdJBPNbuJisY6TgykeI6yYzKseujglK7PX1HtoOm4QWmjlVCN'], 'encounter_date': ['10/10/2021  13:18 PM'], 'animal': ['5'], 'numPerDayField': ['0 (out of 4)'], 'user': ['1'], 'handling_time': [''], 'crate_time': [''], 'holding_time': [''], 'comments': ['']}>
[10/Oct/2021 13:19:29] "POST /encounters/openencounter/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4590
[10/Oct/2021 13:19:29] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 77
```

and the form displays error message: "Enter a valid date/time."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the DateTimeInput widget calling `value_from_datadict` **before** the field's to_python method was called.  So the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/) are a little misleading when it says: *"The to_python() method on a Field is the first step in every validation."*  Even though the DateTimeInput widget accepts the AM/PM format string, and displays the datetime according to that string, it drops the time portion and returns only the date.  So the solution was to subclass the input widget and write a new `value_from_datadict` method for it.  Here is my first draft, which works:

```
class ampmDateTimeInput(DateTimeInput):
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):        
        theRawDate = data['encounter_date']
        theConvertedDate = theRawDate
        # check if there is an AM or PM on the end
        if (len(theRawDate) > 2): 
            theStr = theRawDate[-2:]
            print ('theStr: ', theStr)
            if (theStr == 'PM'):
                #convert to 24 hr format
                #get the hours
                theHrsStr = theRawDate[12:14]
                theHrs = int(theHrsStr)
                theHrs = theHrs + 12
                #pad with leading zero if needed
                theHrsStr = str(theHrs)
                if (len(theHrsStr) == 1):
                    theHrsStr = '0' + theHrsStr
                theConvertedDate = theConvertedDate[0:11] + theHrsStr + theConvertedDate[14:17]
            elif (theStr == 'AM'):
                #just strip the AM
                theConvertedDate = theConvertedDate[0:17] 
            #else just pass the existing string; the user has removed the AM or PM manually    

        # create a mutable instance of the data     
        aNewData = data.copy()
        aNewData['encounter_date'] = theConvertedDate
        return(super().value_from_datadict(aNewData, files, name))
```